# I want to use the output of Solve and/or Reduce in next steps. But the output comes in the form of a rule

Tags: equation-solving, output

In a program I want to use the output of Solve and/or Reduce in next steps. But the output comes in the form of a rule, where what I want is the numerical solution. Here is an example. Say I write s=Solve[x+2==5,x]. In the next step I want to use this solution, so I write: y=2 s +3. This returns {{3+2(x->3)}}. This is a very basic need, but hours combing through the documentation leads nowhere.

Comment: define `s` as `s = x /. Solve[x + 2 == 5, x][[1]]` or as `s = Solve[x + 2 == 5, x][[1, 1, 2]]`?

Comment: kglr: Thank you. That worked. This seems like a basic need, but the method is impossible to find in documentation. Artes: the answer is "no". In fact that is an example of how frustration is turned into ire.

Comment: You could also make a helper function like `SolveValue[args__] := First[Solve[args]][[1, 2]]`

Comment: In the docs for `Solve`, under "Scope" > "Basic Uses", the first example shows `sol = Solve[..]`, then `x /. sol`, which is pretty much the first suggestion of @ kglr.  The main difference is that `Solve` always gives a list of solutions, and often when there is only one solution, one wants the solution itself, not a list containing it. Hence the `[[1]]` added to `Solve[..]`.